# find all files except e.g. *.xml files in shell

Tags: regex, bash, shell, find

Using bash, how to find files in a directory structure except for *.xml files?
I'm just trying to use

```
find . -regex ....
```

regexe:

```
'.*^((?!xml).)*$'
```

but without expected results...

or is there another way to achieve this, i.e. without a regexp matching?

Comment: Three times a great answer! Which one shall I award the accepted answer? the dilemma...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`find . ! -name "*.xml" -type f`

Comment: can you please explain how this works with the parents around the -name param to find?

Answer (score 9):

```
find . -not -name '*.xml'
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Sloppier than the `find` solutions above, and it does more work than it needs to, but you could do

```
find . | grep -v '\.xml$'
```

Also, is this a tree of source code?  Maybe you have all your source code and some XML in a tree, but you want to only get the source code?  If you were using [ack](http://betterthangrep.com), you could do:

```
ack -f --noxml
```

Comment: thanks for the hint concerning ack. Didn't know about ack before.

Answer (score 2):

with bash:

```sh
shopt -s extglob globstar nullglob
for f in **/*!(.xml); do 
    [[ -d $f ]] && continue
    # do stuff with $f
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with or-ring as follows:

`find . -type f -name "*.xml" -o -type f -print`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this for a regex solution:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -not -regex '^.*\.xml$'
```